# Why is Akka spinningup a new thread for processing each message?

Tags: scala, akka, actor, akka-actor

Logs:

```
02:10:23.594 [scala-execution-context-global-3347] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2033.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:10:23.594 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:10:29.704 [scala-execution-context-global-3348] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2034.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:10:29.705 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:10:35.784 [scala-execution-context-global-3349] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2035.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:10:35.784 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:10:41.914 [scala-execution-context-global-3350] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2036.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:10:41.914 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:10:48.074 [scala-execution-context-global-3351] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2037.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:10:48.074 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:10:54.194 [scala-execution-context-global-3352] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2038.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:10:54.194 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:11:00.284 [scala-execution-context-global-3353] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2039.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:11:00.284 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:11:06.405 [scala-execution-context-global-3354] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2040.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:11:06.405 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:11:12.505 [scala-execution-context-global-3355] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2041.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:11:12.505 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:11:18.594 [scala-execution-context-global-3356] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2042.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:11:18.594 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:11:24.674 [scala-execution-context-global-3357] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2043.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:11:24.674 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:11:30.744 [scala-execution-context-global-3358] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2044.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:11:30.744 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:11:36.854 [scala-execution-context-global-3359] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2045.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:11:36.854 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:11:42.974 [scala-execution-context-global-3360] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2046.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:11:42.974 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:11:49.074 [scala-execution-context-global-3361] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2047.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:11:49.074 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:11:55.194 [scala-execution-context-global-3362] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2048.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:11:55.194 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:12:01.254 [scala-execution-context-global-3363] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2049.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:12:01.254 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:12:07.344 [scala-execution-context-global-3364] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2050.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:12:07.347 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:12:13.444 [scala-execution-context-global-3365] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2051.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:12:13.444 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:12:19.544 [scala-execution-context-global-3366] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2052.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:12:19.544 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:12:25.624 [scala-execution-context-global-3367] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2053.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:12:25.624 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:12:31.744 [scala-execution-context-global-3368] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2054.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:12:31.744 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:12:37.824 [scala-execution-context-global-3369] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2055.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:12:37.824 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:12:43.894 [scala-execution-context-global-3370] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2056.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:12:43.894 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:12:49.974 [scala-execution-context-global-3371] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2057.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:12:49.974 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:12:56.064 [scala-execution-context-global-3372] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2058.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:12:56.065 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:13:02.134 [scala-execution-context-global-3373] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2059.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:13:02.135 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:13:08.244 [scala-execution-context-global-3374] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2060.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:13:08.244 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:13:14.344 [scala-execution-context-global-3375] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2061.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:13:14.345 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:13:20.445 [scala-execution-context-global-3376] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2062.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:13:20.445 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:13:26.524 [scala-execution-context-global-3377] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2063.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:13:26.525 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:13:32.595 [scala-execution-context-global-3378] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2064.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:13:32.597 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:13:38.685 [scala-execution-context-global-3379] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2065.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:13:38.685 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:13:44.804 [scala-execution-context-global-3380] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2066.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:13:44.804 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:13:50.874 [scala-execution-context-global-3381] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2067.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:13:50.875 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:13:56.954 [scala-execution-context-global-3382] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2068.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:13:56.954 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:14:03.039 [scala-execution-context-global-3383] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2069.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:14:03.039 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:14:09.124 [scala-execution-context-global-3384] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2070.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:14:09.124 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:14:15.204 [scala-execution-context-global-3385] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2071.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:14:15.204 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:14:21.284 [scala-execution-context-global-3386] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2072.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:14:21.284 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:14:27.404 [scala-execution-context-global-3387] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2073.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:14:27.404 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:14:33.504 [scala-execution-context-global-3388] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2074.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:14:33.504 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:14:39.584 [scala-execution-context-global-3389] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2075.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:14:39.585 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:14:45.695 [scala-execution-context-global-3390] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2076.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:14:45.695 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:14:51.814 [scala-execution-context-global-3391] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2077.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:14:51.815 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:14:57.924 [scala-execution-context-global-3392] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2078.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:14:57.925 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:15:03.994 [scala-execution-context-global-3393] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2079.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:15:03.997 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:15:10.124 [scala-execution-context-global-3394] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2080.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:15:10.124 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:15:16.244 [scala-execution-context-global-3395] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2081.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:15:16.244 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:15:22.345 [scala-execution-context-global-3396] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2082.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:15:22.345 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:15:28.424 [scala-execution-context-global-3397] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2083.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:15:28.424 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:15:34.524 [scala-execution-context-global-3398] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2084.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:15:34.524 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:15:40.644 [scala-execution-context-global-3399] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2085.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:15:40.644 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:15:46.744 [scala-execution-context-global-3400] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2086.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:15:46.744 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:15:52.844 [scala-execution-context-global-3401] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2087.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:15:52.846 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:15:58.944 [scala-execution-context-global-3402] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2088.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:15:58.944 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:16:05.064 [scala-execution-context-global-3403] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2089.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:16:05.064 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:16:11.195 [scala-execution-context-global-3404] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2090.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:16:11.195 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:16:17.334 [scala-execution-context-global-3405] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2091.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:16:17.334 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:16:23.434 [scala-execution-context-global-3406] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2092.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:16:23.434 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:16:29.534 [scala-execution-context-global-3407] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2093.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:16:29.535 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:16:35.624 [scala-execution-context-global-3408] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2094.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:16:35.624 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:16:41.724 [scala-execution-context-global-3409] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2095.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:16:41.725 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:16:47.834 [scala-execution-context-global-3410] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2096.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:16:47.834 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:16:53.964 [scala-execution-context-global-3411] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2097.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:16:53.964 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:17:00.074 [scala-execution-context-global-3412] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2098.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:17:00.075 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:17:06.184 [scala-execution-context-global-3413] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2099.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:17:06.184 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:17:12.274 [scala-execution-context-global-3414] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2100.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:17:12.274 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:17:18.374 [scala-execution-context-global-3415] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2101.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:17:18.374 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:17:24.464 [scala-execution-context-global-3416] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2102.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:17:24.464 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:17:30.554 [scala-execution-context-global-3417] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2103.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:17:30.554 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:17:36.664 [scala-execution-context-global-3418] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2104.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:17:36.664 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:17:42.774 [scala-execution-context-global-3419] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2105.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:17:42.776 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:17:48.914 [scala-execution-context-global-3420] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2106.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:17:48.914 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:17:55.014 [scala-execution-context-global-3421] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2107.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:17:55.014 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:18:01.144 [scala-execution-context-global-3422] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2108.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:18:01.144 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:18:07.234 [scala-execution-context-global-3423] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2109.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:18:07.234 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:18:13.334 [scala-execution-context-global-3424] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2110.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:18:13.335 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:18:19.424 [scala-execution-context-global-3425] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2111.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:18:19.425 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:18:25.564 [scala-execution-context-global-3426] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2112.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:18:25.564 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:18:31.654 [scala-execution-context-global-3427] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2113.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:18:31.654 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:18:37.744 [scala-execution-context-global-3428] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2114.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:18:37.744 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:18:43.825 [scala-execution-context-global-3429] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2115.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:18:43.825 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:18:49.954 [scala-execution-context-global-3430] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2116.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:18:49.954 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
02:18:56.104 [scala-execution-context-global-3431] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[0 Messages in Queue. Empty Queries: 2117.  Backoff: 5000 ms]
02:18:56.104 [my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  c.d.i.service.SchedulerActor - Searching
```

Code:

```
override def receive: Receive = {
    case Search =>
        logger.info("Searching")

        val work = getWork()
        val workLeft = getWorkLeft()

        self ! ScheduleNextSearch(workLeft)

        self ! Work(work)

    case ScheduleNextSearch(workLeft) =>
        if (workLeft == 0) noResultQueries += 1 else noResultQueries=0

        val backoff = if(noResultQueries < 100) 100 else 5000
        cancellable = Some(context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(backoff.milli) {
        logger.info(s"SEARCH scheduled from scheduler[${workLeft} Messages in Queue. Empty SQS Queries: ${noResultQueries}.  Backoff: ${backoff} ms]")
        self ! Search
    )}
}
```

Issue:
I have two search related messages in my actor

1. One searches a Queue for any Jobs to process and Delegates them to some other code to run
2. The second decides how long to wait before checking the Queue again

I don't understand why the second message always gets logged in a new thread?
scala-execution-context-global-3350
scala-execution-context-global-3351
scala-execution-context-global-3352
scala-execution-context-global-3353

The first one is always logged by the same thread
my-service-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8